# localhost:8080 access denied from vs code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, localhost, access-denied

I am very new at javascript and I'm just trying to run a simple code using the chrome debugger. This is my code:

```
document.write("Hello world");

console.log("Hello World");
```

And I get the error: "The web page is not available. Localhost denied access."

[This is what the page looks like, although the message is in norwegian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYvVr.png)

Please help

Answer (score 1):

The localhost method will only work when a backend technology like node js or php.

If you just want to run the file create an HTML file in the same directory and open it with a browser after pasting the following code.`<script type="text/javascript" src="name-of-your-js-file.js"></script>`